# How to make linear overlay in tailwind css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

How to add the linear background like this in tailwind css(not in tailwind.config.js because the image will be fetched from backend)
I want the linear on the image from bottom to top with the softly background
Here is the results i want and the figma design color
[image: Results] [image: Figma Color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `div` above your image background as a layer, something like:

```
<div
  className="h-40 w-40 rounded bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover"
  style={{ background: `url(${'your-url'})` }}
>
  <div className="w-full h-full bg-gradient-to-b from-white">
    <span>Alpha Salcedo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```